# Getting system info from Spring Boot Actuator

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-boot-actuator

I have an SpringBoot app. 2.1.3.RELEASE securized by JWT, I want to add an actuator. I added this dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I have added this properties to the `application.properties` file

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

when I access to `/actuator` I got this response:

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://127.0.0.1:1133/tdk/actuator",
            "templated": false
        },
        "health": {
            "href": "http://127.0.0.1:1133/tdk/actuator/health",
            "templated": false
        },
        "health-component": {
            "href": "http://127.0.0.1:1133/tdk/actuator/health/{component}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "health-component-instance": {
            "href": "http://127.0.0.1:1133/tdk/actuator/health/{component}/{instance}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "info": {
            "href": "http://127.0.0.1:1133/tdk/actuator/info",
            "templated": false
        }
    }
}
```

but when I access to `http://127.0.0.1:1133/tdk/actuator/info` , I got only

```
{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `build-info` goal to generate build information. [see doc here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/howto.html#howto-build-info)  for more info.